# Correct path formatting for python with subfolders to avoid error 2

Tags: python, pandas

This might be very basic question but I struggle to find an answer:

Let's say I have a data structure like this:

```
.
├── main.py
└── scripts
    ├── script.py
    └── data
        └── data.csv
```

`script.py` in being executed from inside `main.py` like this:

```
exec(open('./scripts/script.py').read()
```

`script.py` contains the following line:

```
filepath = './data/data.csv'
data_df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

When I execute `python main.py` from conda command line - all is fine and all 3 files are being processed.

The problem is when I instead execute `python script.py` (for testing) from command line and it returns an error 2: file not found.

I noticed that if I change `filepath = './data/data.csv'` to `filepath = '../data/data.csv'` - it works, but then the same error occurs when I execute the `main.py` again.

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong? How can I improve the code?

EDIT:

So I missed something very basic: I thought that ./ and ../ are equivalent but they are not:

./ refers to the current directory
../ refers to the parent directory

I'll leave this gem here for future generations of misguided people...

Comment: First of all, you should just be using `import`s rather than `exec(open('./scripts/script.py').read())`. Secondly, file paths are given from your current working directory, not from the script's directory. If you want the script's directory, use something like `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` or similar.

Comment: @Axe319, that's fair point about import and I'm modyfing this already.
I think I know where the problem is now... I'll add an edit.